# What dependency do I need to use RestTemplateBuilder with SpringBoot 3 and a Multimodule(J9) project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am building a multimodule (Java 9 feature) application using SpringBoot 3 and I cannot add the correct dependency to RestTemplateBuilder.

My build.gradle (main project) is this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
}

group = 'com.mrv'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

bootJar {
    mainClass = 'com.mrv.lendyourstocks.LendyourstocksApplication'
}

bootRun {
    mainClass = 'com.mrv.lendyourstocks.LendyourstocksApplication'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }

    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    java {
        modularity.inferModulePath = true
    }
}

def modules= [
        "remote",
        "core",
        "api"
]

dependencies {
    modules.collect { implementation project(it)}
}
```

My build gradle, inside the module remote:

```
bootRun {
    enabled = false
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web'
}
```

And finally, module-info.java:

```
module lendyourstocks.remote.main {
    requires spring.boot.starter.web;
    requires spring.web;    
}
```

With single module projects I am able to access it just adding the Spring Web Starter dependency. So I think I am missing something inside the module-info.java file.

Comment: What is the problem you’re facing?

Comment: Java could not find the org.springframework.boot.web.client during compilation. I just solved it adding "requires spring.boot;" to module-info.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing the module-info.java as following:

```
module lendyourstocks.remote.main {
    requires spring.boot;
}
```